# What is the correct syntax for a nested if statement in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

If I have the following code

```
if k=="*":
    match()

    if k1 ==1:
        match()

        if k2==1:
            match()

            if k3==1:
                match()

                if k4=="*":
                    match()
```

Where would I put the corresponding `else` for each `if` statement?

Comment: At the indentation level corresponding to the `if`

Comment: so for the first if statement, would the else be on line 3 on the very bottom line?

Comment: The answer depends on the logic of your program. You did not tell us anything about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the most beautiful, but it would be at the same indentation level as the if statement it corresponds to.

```
if k=="*":
    match()

    if k1 ==1:
        match()

        if k2==1:
            match()

            if k3==1:
                match()

                if k4=="*":
                    match()
                else:
                    print("k4 not match")
            else:
                print("k3 not match")
        else:
            print("k2 not match")
    else:
        print("k1 not match")
else:
    print("k not match")
```

Answer (score 0):

At the same identation level, eg.:

```
            if k=="*":
                match()

                if k1 ==1:
                    match()
                else:
                    doesnt_match(k1) 

                    if k2==1:
                        match()

            else:
                doesnt_match(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend on if you want to next `if` to be evaluated if the parent `if` is true or false. If you wanted to add `else` statements that get evaluated if the parent `if` is false, you would:

```
    if k=="*":
        match()
    else:
        # Do Something bofore next if
        if k1 ==1:
            match()
        else:
            # Do Something before next if
            if k2==1:
                match()
```

If you didn't have anything to do fore the next if, you could eliminate the nesting and do something like:

```
if k == "*":
        match()
elif k1 == 1:
        match()
```

And continue, following that pattern

Answer (score -1):

```
if ....:
    if ...:
        if....:



        else:
    else:
else
```

Try this

Comment: Python is case sensitive, using `If` would give you a syntax error.